# How to use 'used to' two times in a sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrases

How to say this

> "When I used to go to the college, I used to play Volleyball".

Or is it ok to use `used to` two times in a sentence?

I know I can also use something like:

> "When I was in college, I used to play Volleyball"

But I want to know how can I use `used to` 2 times correctly, or is the one that I used in first statement correct?

Comment: You just did use it two times. It's not clear what you're asking beyond that.

Comment: Why are you so keen to use it twice when you know how to avoid doing so? Your second example reads much better.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes sir I used it two times, but I am not sure if it is correct to do so?

Comment: @KateBunting This is the one example I just got in my mind, in the past while speaking, many times I had gone through a phase, where I found this issue, when I had to use `used to` two times.

Comment: Now I’m not as used to using ‘used to’ like I used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-native  speakers   often  use   **used  to**    instead  of  the  simple  past thinking that  only  **used to**  is  used  to  talk about  past  habits  which are  no longer in  use.

Your  sentences  may be  grammatically  correct  but  no  native  speaker  uses **used to** twice  in  a sentence.

They  might say :

> When I was  in college,  I  played  volleyball.

or

> When I was  in college, I would  play volleyball.

Your second sentence  is  better. Your first  sentence  is  rather awkward.

MacMillan Dictionary has an [article that explains “used to”](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/used-to_1) usage in more detail.

Comment: I used to bike every day but now I’m not used to that much exercise.

Comment: @Jim   In your example  the  second  used  is  an adjective.That  is  a different  use

Comment: I know. I did it on purpose.

Comment: I think it is a little misleading to say that native speakers would never use “used to” twice in a sentence. I understand you mean we wouldn’t say “When I used to live in Maine, I used to eat lobster every day.” but it comes across as saying there is never a situation where it’s idiomatic to use “used to” twice.

Answer (score -1):

Anytime you put a comma into your sentence you allow for a whole new sentence about anything. So any subject in the sentence after the comma can use the same phrase.

Comment: Commas don't delimit sentences. Please could you clarify?

Comment: It makes sense with no comma even.